# Why isn't Continue stopping an if loop breaking?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of named polygons:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gp
df = gp.GeoDataFrame([['a',Polygon([(1, 0), (1, 1), (2,2), (1,2)])],
                    ['b',Polygon([(1, 1), (2,2), (3,1)])]],
                    columns = ['name','geometry'])
df = gp.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry = 'geometry')
```

and a list of named points:

```
points = gp.GeoDataFrame( [['box', Point(1.5, 1.75)],
                          ['cone', Point(3.0,2.0)],
                        ['triangle', Point(2.5,1.25)]],
                     columns=['id', 'geometry'], 
                     geometry='geometry')
```

I want to return a list of the names of the points that fall within the polygon and the name of the polygon they fall in with the code:

```
n=0
for name in points:
    if df['geometry'][n].contains(points['geometry'][n]) == True:
        print(points['id'][n],df['name'][n]) 
    n+=1
```

This returns the first point but then the loop breaks at the second point because the `if` statement returns `False`.

I have tried to get the loop to move onto the next iteration with the `continue` statement like so:

```
n=0
for name in points:
    if df['geometry'][n].contains(points['geometry'][n]) == True:
        print(points['id'][n],df['name'][n]) 
    n+=1
    continue
```

But this still only returns the result of the first point and polygon.

How do I stop the 'False' result breaking the loop?

Comment: `continue` isn't doing anything there because that is what the loop would do anyway. The `if` statement isn't breaking out of the loop because it does not contain a `break` statement.

Comment: An unconditional `continue` at the end of a `for` loop has no effect.

Comment: @kindall I see, in which case I must be misunderstanding what is going on in the original loop. Why does it not continue onto the third point in the original code?

Comment: You are looping over `name` in `points`. But it seems like you really want to loop over a range of `n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the for-loop not correctly. `point` only contains one entry.

```
for geo1, name, geo2, id in zip(df['geometry'], df['name'], points['geometry'], points['id']):
    if geo1.contains(geo2):
        print(id, name)
```

or do you want to compare each df-geometry with each point?

```
for geo1, name in zip(df['geometry'], df['name']):
    for geo2, id in zip(points['geometry'], points['id']):
        if geo1.contains(geo2):
            print(id, name)
```

Comment: Yes! That second code works, thank you very much. I'm afraid that I'm not familiar with `zip`, is it doing here?